# Programmatically changing app language on older android versions

Tags: java, android, locale

I am using this code to change the app language at runtime and it works well on android 8 and above, however it doesn't work on android 7 and below.
Can anyone help me fix this, or show me a better way of giving the user the option to change the app language at runtime across all activities?

```
private void setLocale(String lang) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(lang);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString(MY_LANG, lang);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public void loadLocale() {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String languages = prefs.getString(MY_LANG, "");
        setLocale(languages);

    }
```

Comment: You could try to use a library, https://github.com/akexorcist/Localization is something I use and it actually works fairly well.

Comment: @ChristianoBolla it maintain the selected language when the app is closed,right?

Comment: Yes it does! It gets saved to the sharedPreferences by the library.

Answer (score 0):

The below code is 100% working for me on every Android version:

**Save language:**

```
public void setLocal(String lang) {
    Resources res = getContext().getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    conf.setLocale(new Locale(lang));
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
    getActivity().recreate();   // to change app language runtime, e.g. in Settings

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putString(MY_LANG, lang);
    editor.apply();
 }
```

**Load language:**

```
public void loadLanguage(String lang) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String lang = prefs.getString(MY_LANG, "");

    Resources res = getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    conf.setLocale(new Locale(lang));
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
}
```

You have to call loadLanguage() method in each activity.

The best solution is to extend all of your activities from a base activity, and implement the loadLanguage() method there. Make sure to call it both in onCreate and onResume (and maybe in onConfigurationChanged too).

Unfortunately, activity titles can change from selected language, so include the following line in each activity's onCreate method:

```
setTitle(R.string.activity_title);
```